# Resolve EJB Dependencies without a container

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, ejb

I am currently working on a solution for testing EJB 3 Services with JUnit. 
(Yes, I have looked at ejb3unit but it doesn't work for me. Yes, I have looked at container-integrated testing with openEJB but that didn't work out neither..)

So my question is what would be the way for resolving @EJB annotated Dependencies? And I don't mean by using a DI Framework like Weld, Guice or Spring. The solution should be applicable for plain old JUnit Tests -> without using an EJB Container like JBoss, Glassfish or openEJB.

I was able to replace the injection of the entity manager via @PersistenceContext with a little hack using java reflections. So how would I do that for dependencies with @EJB annotation?

(I wouldn't mind building and resolving the dependency tree myself, just looking for ideas ;) )

Greetings from Germany,
p.s.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're against the solution you proposed. 
I was about to offer stuff like [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html), but hey - you don't want to have a container involved. 
I just want to be sure about the reason you don't want container, before I move on to some ideas (though I did not test them) - 
With JBoss AS 7.x deployment time of enterprise application servers was vastly reduced, 
Not to mention that with Arquillian you have a deployment API, and you can decide what you will deploy (i.e - deploy for example just a single bean for a given test). 
However, I do respect you question, so here are some ideas - 
A. You mentioned you managed to inject an EntityManager using reflection - how did you do that? 
 Why not apply the same to your beans? 
B. If you're encountering problems with A, why not develop your own injection code , based on [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) , for example (in order to create Proxy not just for interface, but also for classes). 
This way, when an object of the class is created, 
you will be able to intercept the default CTOR, 
 and scan for fields annotated with @Ejb. 
I would suggest using some sort of configuration file that maps for each bean interface how to instantiate an appropriate class, and run this flow recurisevely (as the injected bean might have a field with @EJB annotation as well). 
Pay attention that if you decide to use this method of work, you'll be implementing some sort of "mini dependnecy injection framework"  - besides the fact that personally I would be interested in seeing your code ( :) ) I think you should carefully think why you don't want to use an "already made solution.

Comment: Regarding "why not arquillian" look at my comment below ;) 

As for the injection of the EntityManager.. 
we have an EJB Service which encapsulates the entity manager. This service only has one interface. So i checked against the interface type via reflections and injected a "real" javax.persistence.entitymanager via java reflections. 
(turns out with reflections private fields aren't that private.. ;) 

As for the other EJBs.. it occurred to me as well that i'd have to traverse the whole dependency chain or fallback to something like a mapping-configuration file. But thx for your response =)

Answer (score 1):

Note regarding the Arquillian suggestions, that still requires an EJB Container like JBoss, GlassFish, or OpenEJB.

If the problem is just finding and including all the dependencies, try this jar that includes all the required dependencies for EJB Lite:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/openejb/openejb-lite/4.0.0/openejb-lite-4.0.0.jar

Include that in your test classpath (no other jars needed) then just boot the embedded container:

```
EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
MyBean bean = (MyBean) container.getContext().lookup("java:global/myModleName/MyBean");
```

Working example [here](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless/README.html)

Comment: hmm, I gave it a try but an Exception is thrown when trying to create the EJBContainer (specifically at EJBContainer.createEJBContainer()): "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ejb.ApplicationException.inherited()" The full stacktrace can be found here: http://pastebin.com/gk3HFw25

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at Arquillian? 
You can find all the documentation on the project page: http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html

Comment: He does not want to involve a container, afaik you need a container for that.

Comment: I'm working with a really old code-base, running on JBoss 4.2. I gave Arquillian several shots but with JBoss 4.2 I really had trouble getting it to work. (If someone would point me to a howto regarding the configuration of arquillian with jboss 4.2 I might consider it again.) I certainly don't want to "reinvent the wheel" but I think it also would be a nice challenge to write my own little DI framework ;)